# IIS increase in worker process memory when RAM is increased

Tags: iis, windows-server-2012

I have a few IIS servers serving web traffic.

In the past these were running off 4GB of RAM and the available RAM was always around 500MB of available RAM, there are 6 app pools and thus 6 worker processes.

When I upped the RAM to 8GB it looks like the worker processes are consuming more memory despite no code change, is this expected due to how IIS works ? i.e. if I increase RAM will the same worker processes be more liberal with their memory usage? (or potentially not garbage collect as often?).

Can anyone explain this?

Comment: 1) If your web apps are ASP.NET 4.x based, then by nature their memory usage is not fully optimized (check the huge improvements in .NET Core if you like). 2) Garbage collector is also kind of lazy to reclaim memory and only does that when really needed, https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/garbage-collection/fundamentals#conditions-for-a-garbage-collection

Comment: The app is managing it's memory use.  If more RAM is available, it will use it.  I've seen this with Windows Update Services web services.  it loves a lot of RAM but will manage with less than it nneeds